# Gerrit image compare

Tags: gerrit

I want to enable diff for images in gerrit. After looking into the documentation

https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#mimetype

```
[mimetype "image/*"]
  safe = true
```

was added for all images. We are running Gerrit Code Review (2.13.3), so in my opinion the image diff should already work.

What the diff looks like

```
index 84873aa..8bf6da5 100644
--- a/Graphics/hand_bitmap.png
+++ b/Graphics/hand_bitmap.png
Binary files differ
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a bug in the current releases, see:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=5197